# Mobile Safari IOS 6 Take a picture

Tags: mobile, file-upload, ios6, safari, camera

I'm looking into the file upload on IOS6 and know that this is possible with the usual link:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Altho, the most tutorials and issues I can find are mostly about the **upload** function. In my case I need to be able to take a picture inside mobile safari with the build-in camera.

I have set up a page to test this (no code, only the link I posted above), and when I take a picture the app (camera app) crashes without actually saving my picture. Is this normal behaviour? Do I need to add some code to upload the picture first? Altho this last thing doesn't make sence to me, since you need to add an already saved picture to a file upload link.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I guess you need some sort of backend... I believe you are photographer so I would actually recommend https://github.com/firebase/firepano or filepicker.io --> save some hassle at the early stage.

Comment: This question may be two years old but the issue seems to persist in iOS 8. @bananam00n have you had any luck resolving the issue?

Comment: @JRulle I remember just continuing my upload function and that fixed the whole problem. I looked through my old code again and didn't find anything else than the code above. Sorry buddy :-(

Comment: @Bananam00n what do you mean by continuing your upload function?

Comment: @JRulle Uploading the file to the server :-). When a picture was taken with the code above, a function was called to upload the image to the server. When that was all finished, the camera didn't crash anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You should not need anything more in the code to avoid crash. It should work the same as choosing a picture from the library. I have tested this on an iPhone 4S with iOS7 and my Safari crashes too. It does not crash every time if I take a picture with the front facing camera (smaller picture?). It also works if I only load the picture from the photo library.

This is a bug in iOS I think. I managed to go around it by restarting my phone. Sadly there is not much we can do on the web side of things, except inform the user that the feature may be buggy.

Comment: I wonder if it could be a memory thing. Mobile Safari crashes out unceremoniously if it exceeds a secret memory limit; as you note, front camera images are a good deal smaller than back camera images.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best recommendation, until Apple provides a fix in a future update, would be to caution your user to close down the rest of their Safari tabs. (This lowers the memory usage and prevents Safari from crashing when doing the 'Take Photo' path through file upload).